# Cannot remove default apps on TCL 30 XE 5G using ADB shell

Tags: adb, uninstallation, system-apps, bloatware

I'm trying to remove a few apps that came pre-installed on my TCL 30XE 5G. I read online that I could use the... ADB, SDK, something like that, platform tools? So I downloaded those, got the files linked to my phone with USB Debugging, and tried the uninstall commands. But nothing worked, and I'm stumped. I tried using the `adb shell` command first, and tried it without, but it didn't make a difference.

Here are some examples of what I tried, and what the cmd said in response:

- `pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.podcasts` gave `Failure User version can not delete system package [com.google.android.apps.podcasts]`
- `pm uninstall com.google.android.apps.podcasts` gave `Failure to remove user owner's system package :com.google.android.apps.podcasts`

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I can try? Bear in mind this is my first ever smartphone, so you may have to explain things like I'm five. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to run any of these commands? `pm hide --user 0 com.google.android.apps.podcasts` OR `pm disable-user --user 0 com.google.android.apps.podcasts`

Comment: The disable command works, although I could already disable the app from the apps menu. The hide command though, gives the following error: [link](https://i.imgur.com/r1s8zOH.png)